# Selecting specific text from the webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, text, webbrowser-control

So I'm new to working with browsers in Win-forms and I'm stuck a particular point.

What i want to do, for the browser to open a page(I've gotten this far). Once the page is open it must navigate to a particular part(It'somewhere in the middle of the page) and select it. Then copy and store it for when i need it, just the text.

I've been able to select all the text on a page by using the following code just as an example:

```
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
    wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
    richTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

It can work for my program but I want to know if there is better way that will select just the text or info I need. If i can, place them in textboxes, or straight into my database.

This is the link to the page: http://www.lolking.net/news/league-trends-jul30

I want to select and get the info from these sections of the page:

Champion Pick Rates - Top 5 Increases and Decreases

Champion Win Rates - Top 5 Increases and Decreases

Champion Ban Rates - Top 5 Increases and Decreases

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may be better just interacting with the actual page source using something like the HtmlAgilityPack, but a complete answer would be too long for stack overflow

Comment: `wb.DocumentText` is what you're after? Also you need [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), no web browser just download the content as string using `WebRequest` or `WebClient`

Comment: I'll check on that HtmlAgilityPack, I;'m new to this so dont know many of these things. But thanx.

Comment: Is there a way i can use the 'wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll"' to select at a certain point and finish selection at a certain point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is my final solution, it works 100%, it takes your first answer, which you can see ;p and uses my `regex.matches`. I think the part that i added to the `foreach` loops, could be done in a method so you can just call it whenever you need it. I just haven't got to that yet! :)

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> rawhtml = new List<string>(); //List for the whole page
        List<string> list_pick = new List<string>(); //PICK section
        List<string> list_win = new List<string>(); //WIN section
        List<string> list_ban = new List<string>(); //BAN section
        List<string> list_Comp = new List<string>(); //Champion names
        fillchamplist(list_Comp);
        rawhtml = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList(); //FILL the page to list
        int ID_pick = 0;
        int ID_win = 0;
        int ID_ban = 0;
        int ID_cmt = 0; // We need to specify the end of BAN section
        for (int i = 0; i < rawhtml.Count; i++) //Search for the line number of section-start
        {
            if (rawhtml[i] == "Champion Pick Rates") ID_pick = i;
            if (rawhtml[i] == "Champion Win Rates") ID_win = i;
            if (rawhtml[i] == "Champion Ban Rates") ID_ban = i;
            if (rawhtml[i].Contains("Comments")) ID_cmt = i;
        }
        // PICK
        for (int i = ID_pick; i < ID_pick + (ID_win - ID_pick); i++) //Calculate the start and the end line-number
        {
            list_pick.AddRange(Regex.Split(rawhtml[i], "(?<=[)])")); //Split the five characters, without losing the ')'
        }
        foreach (var item in list_pick)
        {
            string rtbpicker = item.ToString();
            foreach (var comp in list_Comp)
            {
                int count = 0; //To see which match we working with later
                foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtbpicker, "" + comp.ToString() + "")) // Checks for all matches and cycles through them
                {
                    if (count == 2) // if the count == 2, it means that its on its 3rd match(the one we dont wana give a space to
                    {
                    }
                    else // puts the space in
                    {
                        int matchindex = m.Index;
                        int matchlength = m.Length;
                        if (m.Length >= 2) // only champ names are >=2
                        {
                            rtbpicker = rtbpicker.Insert(matchindex + matchlength + count, "\t"); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rtbpicker = rtbpicker.Insert(matchindex + matchlength + count, " "); // the count variable updates he index so the space doesnt occur before the % sign
                        }


                        if (Regex.Matches(rtbpicker, "" + comp.ToString() + "").Count > 0)// just to update the index for the 2nd %
                        {
                            count++;


                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            rtbPick.AppendText(rtbpicker + System.Environment.NewLine); //Optinal: Add to richtextbox
        }
        // WIN
        for (int i = ID_win; i < ID_win + (ID_ban - ID_win); i++)
        {
            list_win.AddRange(Regex.Split(rawhtml[i], "(?<=[)])"));
        }
        foreach (var item in list_win)
        {
            string rtbpicker = item.ToString();
            foreach (var comp in list_Comp)
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtbpicker, "" + comp.ToString() + ""))
                {
                    if (count == 2)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int matchindex = m.Index;
                        int matchlength = m.Length;
                        if (m.Length >= 2)
                        {
                            rtbpicker = rtbpicker.Insert(matchindex + matchlength + count, "\t");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rtbpicker = rtbpicker.Insert(matchindex + matchlength + count, " ");
                        }


                        if (Regex.Matches(rtbpicker, "" + comp.ToString() + "").Count > 0)
                        {
                            count++;


                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            rtbWin.AppendText(rtbpicker + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
        // BAN
        for (int i = ID_ban; i < ID_ban + (ID_cmt - ID_ban); i++)
        {
            list_ban.AddRange(Regex.Split(rawhtml[i], "(?<=[)])"));
        }
        foreach (var item in list_ban)
        {
            string rtbpicker = item.ToString();
            foreach (var comp in list_Comp)
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtbpicker, "" + comp.ToString() + ""))
                {
                    if (count == 2)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int matchindex = m.Index;
                        int matchlength = m.Length;
                        if (m.Length >= 2)
                        {
                            rtbpicker = rtbpicker.Insert(matchindex + matchlength + count, "\t");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rtbpicker = rtbpicker.Insert(matchindex + matchlength + count, " ");
                        }


                        if (Regex.Matches(rtbpicker, "" + comp.ToString() + "").Count > 0)
                        {
                            count++;


                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            rtbBan.AppendText(rtbpicker + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

This is the outcome:(doesn't show the tabs here for some reason)

> Champion Pick Rates
>
> Top Five Biggest Increases
>
> Lucian 27.75% -> 32.3% (+4.55%)
>
> Ahri   8.7% -> 11.3% (+2.6%)
>
> Rengar 11.25% -> 13.84% (+2.59%)
>
> Nidalee    10.7% -> 12.93% (+2.23%)
>
> Tristana   30.07% -> 32.02% (+1.95%)
>
> Top Five Biggest Decreases
>
> Caitlyn    34.44% -> 30.63% (-3.81%)
>
> Vayne  17.25% -> 15.69% (-1.56%)
>
> Ezreal 15.08% -> 13.6% (-1.48%)
>
> Renekton   13.84% -> 12.6% (-1.24%)
>
> Lee Sin    30.54% -> 23.36% (-7.18%)

Ok so :D that works perfect for me, but that's cause i know what i want the outcome to be for this specific thing. Your method also works and i would actually recommend it for scenarios.

If you got any questions, dont be afraid to ask hey :)

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach loop will look like this:

```
foreach (var item in list_ban)
{

       string rtbpicker = item.ToString();

       foreach (var comp in list_Comp)
       {

           int count = 0; //Counts for the number of occurences

           foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtbpicker, "" + comp.ToString() + ""))
           {

               int matchindex = m.Index;
               int matchlength = m.Length;

               rtbpicker = rtbpicker.Insert(matchindex + matchlength + count, " "); //Count just moves the index forward by however many postions the original index was shifted

               if(Regex.Matches(rtbpicker, "" + comp.ToString() + "").Count > 1)
               {
                  count++;

               }         

            }

       }
            richTextBox6.Text += rtbpicker + "\n";
            //rtbBan.AppendText(rtbpicker + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Got the spaces Working. But now the it still places a space at the last '%' sign. We don't need a space there

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got (yet) the whole solution but I can help you a bit:

Once you got the plain text from the FULLY LOADED webBrowser, and wrote in richTextBox1, then you can print the 3 part to other textboxes:

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> rawhtml = new List<string>(); //List for the whole page
        List<string> list_pick = new List<string>(); //PICK section
        List<string> list_win = new List<string>(); //WIN section
        List<string> list_ban = new List<string>(); //BAN section
        rawhtml = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList(); //FILL the page to list
        int ID_pick = 0;
        int ID_win = 0;
        int ID_ban = 0;
        int ID_cmt = 0; // We need to specify the end of BAN section
        for (int i = 0; i < rawhtml.Count; i++) //Search for the line number of section-start
        {
            if (rawhtml[i] == "Champion Pick Rates") ID_pick = i;
            if (rawhtml[i] == "Champion Win Rates") ID_win = i;
            if (rawhtml[i] == "Champion Ban Rates") ID_ban = i;
            if (rawhtml[i].Contains("Comments")) ID_cmt = i;
        }
        // PICK
        for (int i = ID_pick; i < ID_pick + (ID_win - ID_pick); i++) //Calculate the start and the end line-number
        {
            list_pick.AddRange(Regex.Split(rawhtml[i], "(?<=[)])")); //Split the five characters, without losing the ')'
        }
        foreach (var item in list_pick)
        {
            richTextBox2.AppendText(item + System.Environment.NewLine); //Optinal: Add to richtextbox
        }
        // WIN
        for (int i = ID_win; i < ID_win + (ID_ban - ID_win); i++)
        {
            list_win.AddRange(Regex.Split(rawhtml[i], "(?<=[)])"));
        }
        foreach (var item in list_win)
        {
            richTextBox3.AppendText(item + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
        // BAN
        for (int i = ID_ban; i < ID_ban + (ID_cmt - ID_ban); i++)
        {
            list_ban.AddRange(Regex.Split(rawhtml[i], "(?<=[)])"));
        }
        foreach (var item in list_ban)
        {
            richTextBox4.AppendText(item + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

This code will make output from "Champion Win Rates" like:

---

> Champion Win Rates
>
> Top Five Biggest Increases
>
> Urgot41.38%->43.67%(+2.29%)
>
> Kennen47.7%->49.28%(+1.58%)
>
> Lucian51.61%->53.1%(+1.49%)
>
> Singed48.95%->50.31%(+1.36%)
>
> Fiora53.48%->54.71%(+1.23%)
>
> Top Five Biggest Decreases
>
> Kassadin48.7%->46.67%(-2.03%)
>
> Galio53.18%->51.42%(-1.76%)
>
> Cho'Gath48.03%->46.37%(-1.66%)
>
> Corki50.05%->48.43%(-1.62%)
>
> Graves49.49%->47.98%(-1.51%)

---

Much better... ;)

I'm faced a problem with spaces, but i can't solve it yet.

I hope you understand this, if you have any question please comment!

Ps.: Sorry for bad eng

Pss.: I know this isn't the full solution, but i must share with you :)

Comment: WOW!! Thanx so much

I was working on a similar solution, just mine looked alot longer and alot more complicated! With string editing! Lol so I understood it fine and thanx again for being such a help!

Comment: If i get the solution to the spaces, I will post it here, will work on it again tomorrow

Comment: It will make it alot easier now to store the info, just after the spaces is fixed, so thanx alot again :D

Comment: You're welcome :) It's nice helping the people ;) This space problem flustrating me a bit... Have a nice day :)

Comment: So I kind of got the space issue working and i know what the problem is, i just don't know how to fix it!
So you add another list in:
`List<string> list_Comp = new List<string>(); //all your comparisons e.g champ names and % and > ect.`

Then you add this code to your your foreach loop for the putting the text in each box:

Comment: Ok i posted my thoughts as the next answer, the problem is, if finds three matches for '%' and it inserts the space at the index where it found it. Not the new index after the space was added to the first '%'
@raptor

Comment: I think it could work, if you could update the match indexes after each time it goes through the loop - @RAPTOR

Comment: @Cleave I can't comment there, my rep is tiny as a 3-day member. So I have one problem. What if the champion names changes. I don't think hardcoding the names is the best way, however i haven't got better solution. This night, i want to figure this problem out. Ever. :D

Comment: Okay, i never used Regex, so it's need a little research, howewer one thing is sure: RAW-HTML isn't a way :D

Answer (score 0):

And now the full solution, with perfect spaces. Regex was difficult to me, but I think this is more simple, however longer too.

```
private void btnspace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox6.Text = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < list_ban.Count; i++)
    {
        string rebuilder = ""; //for the output string (one line)
        List<char> temp_chars = list_ban[i].ToCharArray().ToList(); //split one line into char sequence
        int number_occur = 0; //occurence counter for numbers
        int minus_occur = 0;// occurence counter for '-'
        for (int j = 0; j < temp_chars.Count; j++)
        {
            // NUMBERS
            // I don't wanted to hardcode the champions :/
            if (number_occur < 2 && (temp_chars[j] == '1' || temp_chars[j] == '2' || temp_chars[j] == '3' || temp_chars[j] == '4' || temp_chars[j] == '5' || temp_chars[j] == '6' || temp_chars[j] == '7' || temp_chars[j] == '8' || temp_chars[j] == '9' || temp_chars[j] == '0')) //looks pretty, isn't?
            {
                temp_chars.Insert(j, ' '); //insert a space into char seq
                j = j + 5; // in the longest case: 12.34, so skip 5 char, or 1 2. 3 4
                number_occur = number_occur + 1; //for the difference percentage we don't need spaces, so insert by number only twice
            }
            // NUMBERS DONE
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < temp_chars.Count; j++)
        {
            // ( and -
            if (temp_chars[j] == '-' || temp_chars[j] == '(')
            {
                if (temp_chars[j] == '-') minus_occur = minus_occur + 1; //if the difference is negative, there will be one more minus, which doesn't need space
                if (minus_occur <= 1) temp_chars.Insert(j, ' ');
                j = j + 1; //avoid endless loop
            }
            // ( and - DONE
        }
        foreach (var item in temp_chars)
        {
            rebuilder = rebuilder + item; //rebuild the line from the char list, with spaces
        }
        list_ban.RemoveAt(i); //replace the old spaceless lines...
        list_ban.Insert(i, rebuilder);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(list_ban[i] + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

I hope it's clear, i tried to comment everything. Good luck, and feel free to ask. Please mention if it's working because i want to answer this question perfectly :D

Comment: Just to be clear, the part where you did the numbers, was that meant to be the champion names and the %? The champion names, will be read from a database so, they wont be hardcoded :D

Comment: Ooops, okay. I don't know anythink about LoL, so... :D yes, the number part is finds the first number, and then skip 5 char `j = j + 5;` because the longest percent is 4 number plus one dot. Howewer this is a solution for your problem with the last '%' sign @Cleave

Comment: @Cleave, it's nice to see that your question is fully answered. Good luck with programming (too). Bye :)

Comment: Thanx for all the help, I'd really like to work with you again if any issues arise. Where can i get hold of you? :)